# Regex for finding sub-domain in email address

Tags: regex

I have email addresses with a subdomain and I want to get the subdomain of the email address. I have tried a few things, but they are not working. Some things include the `@` which I don't need. So, basically, I want to get email@***subdomain***.domain.com.

Here is what I have that is including the `@`:

`/([@])\w+/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming consistent pattern:

```
(?<=@)[^.]+
```

- `(?<=@)` is zero-width positive lookbehind pattern ensuring our desired match is preceded by `@`
- `[^.]+` matches till the next `.`  i.e. our desired portion

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM2tK4/2)

Comment: That is just what I needed. Do you mind giving a brief explanation of what you are doing so I can better understand? Thanks!

Comment: Thank! Waiting for the 10 minutes to pass so I can mark it correct :)